# C# Class scope issue?

Tags: c#, scope

I am a student.  This is our first project using two different class files, and it is also only the second one using Forms. So, I don't have much experience with either.

The object is declared and instantiated, but the object is not recognized in any of the subsequent methods.  I am following the code on the book.  The code on the book declares/instantiates like this:

```
new Order = new Order( );
```

I think it needs to be like this, but that still doesn't help the subsequent references:

```
Order newOrder = new Order( );
```

This a a complete listing of the driver and the two class files:

Driver:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Diner
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new OrderGUI());
        }
    }
}
```

OrderGUI.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Diner
{
    public partial class OrderGUI : Form
    {
        public OrderGUI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //For Load - create object
        private void OrderGUI_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            newOrder = new Order();

            for (int i = 0; i < newOrder.menuEntree.Length; i++)
            {
                this.lstBxEntree.Items.Add(newOrder.menuEntree[i]);
            }
        }

        // Event handler that gets the entree from the
        // Listbox and sets the entree price of the Order object.
        private void lstBxEntree_SelectedIndexChanged
                           (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            newOrder.Entree = this.lstBxEntree.Text;
        }

        // Event handler that gets the special request -
        // if one is selected from the predefined list.
        private void cmboSpecial_SelectedIndexChanged
                           (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            newOrder.SpecialRequest = this.cmboSpecial.Text;
        }

        // Menu item that displays the order. 
        private void menuDisplayOrder_Click(object sender,
                                            System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Event handler that gets the radio button selected and
        // sets the drink selection for the Order object
        private void Drink_CheckedChanged(object sender,
                                          System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.radTea.Checked)
                newOrder.DrinkSelection = radTea.Text;
            else
                if (this.radCoffee.Checked)
                    newOrder.DrinkSelection = radCoffee.Text;
                else
                    if (this.radSoda.Checked)
                        newOrder.DrinkSelection = radSoda.Text;
                    else
                        if (this.radLemon.Checked)
                            newOrder.DrinkSelection = radLemon.Text;
                        else
                            if (this.radJuice.Checked)
                                newOrder.DrinkSelection = radJuice.Text;
                            else
                                if (this.radMilk.Checked)
                                    newOrder.DrinkSelection = radMilk.Text;
        }

        // Event handler that gets raised when the check box
        // for the Water gets clicked.
        private void ckBxWater_CheckedChanged
                          (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ckBxWater.Checked)
                newOrder.WaterSelection = true;
            else
                newOrder.WaterSelection = false;
        }

        // Event handler that gets raised when the user types
        // values into the text area of the combo box.
        private void cmboSpecial_KeyPress
                           (object sender,
                            System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            newOrder.SpecialRequest = this.cmboSpecial.Text;
        }

        // Event handler that gets raised when the Edit menu 
        // is clicked to change the entree.
        private void menuEditEntree_Click
                           (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Event handler that gets raised when the Edit menu 
        // is clicked to change the drink.
        private void menuEditDrink_Click
                           (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Clears selections for all drink radio buttons. 
        public void ClearDrinks()
        {
            this.radMilk.Checked = false;
            this.radJuice.Checked = false;
            this.radSoda.Checked = false;
            this.radLemon.Checked = false;
            this.radTea.Checked = false;
            this.radCoffee.Checked = false;
        }

        //  Clears all selections so that a new order 
        //  can be placed. Resets the Order object back 
        //  to its default values.
        private void menuClearOrder_Click
                           (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Displays the values for the current instance of
        // Order object members
        private void menuPlaceOrder_Click(object sender,
                                  System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Event handler that gets raised when the Edit menu 
        // is clicked to change the special requests.
        private void menuEditSpecial_Click(object sender,
                                             System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // Event handler that gets raised when the Help 
        // menu is clicked to show the About message.
        private void menuAbout_Click(object sender,
                                       System.EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Student Union -" +
                            " Diner by the Valley" +
                            "\n\n\nVersion 1.0");
        }

        // Event handler that gets raised when the 
        // Exit is clicked
        private void menuExit_Click(object sender,
                                      System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

    }
}
```

Order.cs:
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

```
namespace Diner
{
    public class Order
    {
        public string[] menuEntree = new
            string[] {"Chicken Salad",
                        "Ham and Cheese",
                        "Turkey",
                        "Vegetable Wrap",
                        "Tuna Salad",
                        "Avocado and Cheese",
                        "Club",
                        "Peanut Butter & Jelly",
                        "Cheese Toasty",
                        "Reuben"};
        public decimal[] menuEntreePrice = new
            decimal[] {4.50m,
                        5.00m,
                        4.75m,
                        4.00m,
                        4.50m,
                        4.00m,
                        5.50m,
                        3.75m,
                        3.50m,
                        5.00m};

        private string entree;
        private bool waterSelection;
        private string drinkSelection;
        private string specialRequest;
        private decimal entreePrice;
        private decimal drinkPrice;

        // Default Constructor
        public Order()
        {
            entree = "";
            waterSelection = false;
            specialRequest = "";
            drinkPrice = 0;
            entreePrice = 0;
        }

        //Property for Entree
        public string Entree
        {
            get
            {
                return entree;
            }
            set
            {
                entree = value;
                SetEntreePrice();
            }
        }

        // Property for special request
        public string SpecialRequest
        {
            get
            {
                return specialRequest;
            }
            set
            {
                specialRequest = value;
            }
        }
        // Property for Water Selection
        public bool WaterSelection
        {
            set
            {
                waterSelection = value;
            }
        }

        // Property for Drink Selection
        public string DrinkSelection
        {
            get
            {
                return drinkSelection;
            }
            set
            {
                drinkSelection = value;
                SetDrinkPrice();
            }
        }

        // Read-only property for entreee price
        public decimal EntreePrice
        {
            get
            {
                return entreePrice;
            }
        }

        // Read-only property for drink price
        public decimal DrinkPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return drinkPrice;
            }
        }

        // After the entree is set, store the entree price
        public void SetEntreePrice()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < menuEntree.Length; i++)
            {
                if (menuEntree[i] == entree)
                {
                    entreePrice = menuEntreePrice[i];
                }
            }
        }

        // Return the water selection
        public string GetWaterSelection()
        {
            string waterOrNot;

            if (waterSelection)
            {
                waterOrNot = "Water";
            }
            else
            {
                waterOrNot = "No Water";
            }
            return waterOrNot;
        }

        // After the drink is set, store the drink price
        public void SetDrinkPrice()
        {
            switch (drinkSelection)
            {
                case "Tea":
                case "Coffee":
                    drinkPrice = 1.50m;
                    break;
                case "Soda":
                case "Lemonade":
                    drinkPrice = 2.00m;
                    break;
                case "Milk":
                case "Juice":
                    drinkPrice = 1.75m;
                    break;
            }
        }

        // return the total cost of the order
        public decimal DetermineTotalCharges()
        {
            return entreePrice + drinkPrice;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Toatal Due: " + DetermineTotalCharges().ToString("C");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to declare `newOrder` as a *field* somewhere. Which book are you using? It's pretty awful to get this sort of thing wrong...

Comment: Yes, newOrder needed to be declared at the top of the class.  I'm studying Java, C++ and C# simultaneously.  I have seen numerous errors with all of the books.  This actually helped me learn what not to do.  Thank you for the input!

Comment: Someone wrote a book with this code in?! Something is wrong with our industry.

Comment: In fairness to the authors, the focus of this chapter was event driven programming, so they give you code, where they normally do not.  They need to teach you how to apply scope and multiple classes before they get to this point.